# How to use minimization in python for multidimensional data?

Tags: multidimensional-array, scipy, scipy-optimize, minimization

I have input.dat file for 11 parameters.

Using input.dat, I am running a software and it gives me (row,column)=(100,3) data set. I already have correct (100,3) data set.

Then I calculated cost function or error between this two dataset.

I am trying to use optimize.minimize to find best set of parameters in input.dat such a way I can reduce the error between two data sets or minimize the cost function.

Here input.dat have 11 numbers.

```
y = already have a data (100,3)
y_pred = run the software using input.dat to get data (100,3)
cost_function = y - y_pred
optimize.minimize(cost_funation, input.dat, method="BFGS")
```

Comment: Hi Amit! What is your specific question? Can you tell us what is not working for you?

Comment: I am not able to do it for the dataset having shape (100,3)                                                                    the error is: ValueError: `f0` passed has more than 1 dimension.